# Стиль гиперссылок в PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, php

Никак не удается справиться со стилем гиперссылок при генерации *.xls посредством PHPExcel. Ссылки имеют стиль обычного текста, хотя и доступны для перехода. Ни один вариант не срабатывает.

---

```
$objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E1' , 'http://www.phpexcel.net');
$objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> getCell('I1') -> setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA) ->setValue('=HYPERLINK("http://www.phpexcel.net","http://www.phpexcel.net")');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'www.phpexcel.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://www.phpexcel.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H1')->getHyperlink()->setTooltip('Navigate to website');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

---

Подскажите, может кто знает как это побороть, или, возможно, как использовать заготовки стилей из самого Excel'я.
Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте
>> ->getCell()->getHyperlink()->setUrl('url');
в режиме setReadDataOnly(true) ссылки не работают

Comment: третья строка:

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://www.phpexcel.net');

Не работает.

Answer (score 0):

непонятно в чем у вас проблема

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$row)->getHyperlink()-
>setUrl('http://www.www.com');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$row)-
>getHyperlink()->setTooltip('Your title');
```

это точно работает.
Вероятно вам необходимо попробовать другой тип экспорта. Возможно Excel2007 ?

Comment: вероятно вы говорить о форматировании текста ? тогда это поможет   $styleBoldBlack = array(
   'font'  => array(
   'bold'  => true,
   'color' => array('rgb' => '403e3a'),
  ));  $objSheet->getStyle('B'.$row)->applyFromArray($styleBoldBlack);

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Ссылка текст');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('www.phpexcel.net');
```